# htaccess allow files with regular expression

Tags: regex, .htaccess

I am using htaccess to deny access to my php-files. Nevertheless I need some of them called from outside, e.g. index.php

I came up with

```
<Files a_string_a.php>
Order Allow,Deny
Allow from all
</Files>
```

Works as expected, I can use the file. But I have several files. I want to avoid to write for every files such a block. Is there a chance to explain htaccess that it shall give access to all files that matches

```
..._string_.....PHP? (containing a unique string no matter what else is in the filename)
```

I am pretty sure there is a RegExpress for this but I am kinda lost and not sue how to integrate this into htacess - thank you for a tip.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe like this:

```
<FilesMatch "(index|foo|bar)\.php$">
  Order Allow,Deny
  Allow from all
</FilesMatch>
```

And add any file basename with a | (regex or).

See https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#filesmatch

Answer (score 0):

> `..._string_.....PHP`? (containing a unique string no matter what else is in the filename)

You may be able to use this `FilesMatch` directive with a regex:

```sh
<FilesMatch "(?i)^.*_string_.*\.php$">
  Order Allow,Deny
  Allow from all
</FilesMatch>
```

**RegEx Details:**

- `(?i)`: Enable ignore case matching
- `^`: Start
- `.*`: Match 0 or more of any characters
- `_string_`: Match `_string_`
- `.*`: Match 0 or more of any characters
- `\.php`: Match `.php`
- `$`: End